# How can i share an Xcode 4 project with multiple developers using Subversion

Tags: ios, svn, xcode4, code-sharing

We are multiple developers working on the same Xcode 4 iOS project.  We are trying to commit to use Subversion but we keep getting conflicts with project.pbxproj when 2 developers add a new target or change the project structure.

What is the proper way to go about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Commit & update more often, or modularize your app into several projects if possible. There’s also [mandatory locking](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.locking.html) available in Subversion (`svn:needs-lock`), but I’m not sure if that’s worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem. The way we solved it was by also committing the projectName.xcodeproj file. Basically, the whole top level directory that contained the resource files and project files were committed. We use the subversion system in the organizer. I'm not sure whether you are or are not committing the project file; but if you aren't I suggest you commit that too.

Since we started doing that, we have stopped having conflicts over the project file.

There is one other thing (and this is if you are committing the .xcodeproj file); when you commit, there is an unchecked check box under the .xcodeproj package. Make sure you check that. That way, the project structure changes will be relayed to all the other developers as well. :)

Hope it helps.